# weblogic 12 webservices responses - elements are in alpha order so do not validate against schema

Tags: java, xml, web-services, validation, xsd

Our webservices work as expected on weblogic 10.3; the responses can be validated against the schema. We have recently upgraded to Weblogic 12. We now get responses which contain the proper elements, but the elements have been ordered alphabetically, which gives us schema validation errors.

```
Response running under Weblogic 10.3 - this will validate against the schema.
<response>
    <Aelement>data</Aelement>
    <belement>data</belement>
    <celement>data</celement>
    <Zelement>data</Zelement>
</response>

Response running under WL 12 - this will not validate because the Zelement is
out of proper sequence.
<response>
    <Aelement>data</Aelement>
    <Zelement>data</Zelement>
    <belement>data</belement>
    <celement>data</celement>
</response>
```

Any idea what is happening or what has changed ?

More important, any suggestions what we can do to get the responses to be returned in the the order specified in the xsd files?